# How to tell if a system property comes from human operator, not from default?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, system-properties

I have a JAR-packaged standalone application that, when executed, unpacks itself into a temporal directory and spawns a child process within that directory. The reason being some third-party code and configuration assumes data files are found relative to current working directory, and java has no chdir() method, so the only way is to switch the working dir for a child process.

All works fine, except for the system properties. An operator may decide to specify some system properties in the command line, both standard ones and ones related to the third-party configuration:

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/temp -Dsomething=else -jar foo.jar (parameters)
```

The system properties available to the parent java process are not by default propagated to child. I should do it myself. And here I get into a roadblock: I have no way to tell which properties are set by operator and which are initialized by default by JVM.

Take that java.io.tmpdir one. If operator has provided it, he has a good reason to do so (perhaps the default location is "disk full"). I have to set it to child process, or it will fail. But how do I know if it came from operator? It may be just the default value.

I may try and set **all** available system properties to the child process. It takes a long list though and, worse, fails in some environments where the command line length is limited.

The only workaround I've found so far (quite a wicked one) is to spawn another child process first, with no arguments at all, and let it pipe back to the parent all the system properties it has. The values that match those that parent has are defaults. The rest should be passed down to the worker child process.

Does anyone have a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chosen solution:**

I still had to go with a child process that does nothing but passes the parent all the system properties it gets to compare. The only minor issue I stumbled upon was line.separator property which caused my line reading code stumble on extra empty line. That was easy to fix.

**Why I accepted none of answers:**

Approaches suggested in the answers below are reasonable, but none of them is completely satisfying.

I do not have much power over the users to tell them that Java system properties should be passed via a property file or a special command-line argument. This is awkward and goes against operational practices (special cases are always bad).

I cannot also select a subset of system properties to pass to the child process. System class documentation doesn't tell which ones are OK to overwrite (and common sense replaces no documentation). There is also a facility for end-user to define their own properties, and those I cannot predict neither by name no number.

Answer (score 2):

Where I work, we had a slowly growing list of system properties that users could apply, and while we did not have the child process to worry about, we did have a different issue: there were simply too many.

Rather than making the user supply system properties via the command line (or, in our case, making the line in the script that launches the application yet another property longer), we added support for loading a .properties file by default.

If you can convince users to put permanent properties there, then start the process of launching the child process, and then loading from the file, you could avoid the headache altogether.

Still, you would likely be presented with debug scenarios where temporary, or one-time properties are desired without modifying the file (not that it's really a big deal). You have a few choices here:

1. Continue to use the approach you are currently.
2. Get the user to pass the system properties as command line arguments that *you* then load into system properties for both the parent and child process.
3. Say tough, use the file. (Not a terrible thing, but I would be annoyed with that solution as a user)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good answer to this.  But fortunately, *most* of the standard system properties either can't be overridden, or nobody in their right mind would override.

So the following approaches are probably your best bets:

- pass on the subset of the standard properties that you think that it makes sense to pass on,
- provide a way to specify the JVM options (including -D options) to be used for child JVMs, or
- a combination of the above approaches.